# e1000e error -5 and UNCLAIMED network interface after installing ubuntu newly

Tags: 18.04

I've used Windows, and decided to use Ubuntu and installed on my pc.
But Network is not working.
I've researched this problem, and reached following result.

```
$sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c29000-f7c29fff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

```
$dmesg | grep -e e100
[    1.000006] e1000e: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.000119] e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.000760] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.6.0-NAPI
[    1.000761] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2019 Intel Corporation.
[    1.000967] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.105400] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[    1.163676] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -5
[  102.144745] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.6.0-NAPI
[  102.144747] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2019 Intel Corporation.
[  102.145080] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[  102.255649] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[  102.319673] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -5
```

```
$lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0200]'
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [17aa:4000]
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
```

I've seen many similiar post like this, but any didn't solved.

I've tried to update driver, use bootutil, but nothing not work.
What's the solution?

bootutil's result is as follows.

```
$sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC 1 -defcfg
[sudo] password for hawkofsky: 
Connection to QV driver failed - please reinstall it!

Intel(R) Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility
BootUtil version 1.7.10.10
Copyright (C) 2003-2019 Intel Corporation

ERROR: -DEFCFG not allowed when combo image is present in flash

Port Network Address Location Series  WOL Flash Firmware                Version
==== =============== ======== ======= === ============================= =======
  1   4466E9BDB252     0:25.0 Gigabit YES FLASH Not Present
```

## Update

```
$ sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC=1 -UP=Combo -FILE=BootIMG.FLB
Connection to QV driver failed - please reinstall it!

Intel(R) Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility
BootUtil version 1.7.10.10
Copyright (C) 2003-2019 Intel Corporation

Option ROM area in the flash is not supported for this device on port 1

Port Network Address Location Series  WOL Flash Firmware                Version
==== =============== ======== ======= === ============================= =======
  1   4466E9BDB252     0:25.0 Gigabit YES FLASH Not Present
```

Comment: Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 19.10 DVD/USB and see if that works.

Comment: same as. I've tried just now, but still network is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NVM for your Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection is corrupt.

The Intel® Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility (BootUtil) is used to update configurations and program the PCI option ROM on the flash memory of supported Intel PCI and PCI-Express-based network adapters.

Please download Intel's utility to fix this, from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29137?v=t), read the included docs, and the docs on the web site, then do this...

```
cd APPS/BootUtil/Linux_x64
chmod +x ./bootutil64e
sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC 1 -defcfg
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1197908/network-eth0-missing-the-nvm-checksum-is-not-valid-with-asus-maximus-ix-hero

Source: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29137?v=t

**Update #1:**

Because of this bootutil error:

```
ERROR: -DEFCFG not allowed when combo image is present in flash
```

Try `sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC=1 -UP=Combo`, or download the Windows updater from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/downloads/eula/29137/Intel-Ethernet-Connections-Boot-Utility-Preboot-Images-and-EFI-Drivers?httpDown=https%3A%2F%2Fdownloadmirror.intel.com%2F29137%2Feng%2FPREBOOT.EXE) and do it from Windows.

**Update #2:**

Windows updater downloaded from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Intel-Ethernet-Adapter-Complete-Driver-Pack?product=47620).

Comment: I've tried that as well, but the error occured.

Comment: @thinkmore Did you receive any errors when using the utility? Did you reboot?

Comment: updated the post with bootutil result.

Comment: also tried to ```sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC=1 -DEFAULTCONFIG```, but the same.

Comment: Show me the output of running the bootutil64e with no parameters, and it should tell you what card it sees. Also read the User Guide at https://downloadmirror.intel.com/29137/eng/bootutil.txt and it tells how to handle the combo image that it appears you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106298/discussion-between-thinkmore-and-heynnema).

Comment: @thinkmore  Try `sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC=1 -UP=Combo`, or download the Windows updater and do it from Windows.

Comment: @thinkmore Status please...

Comment: solved. I've posted answer.

Comment: @thinkmore Since my answer solved the problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @thinkmore My answer provided the **exact** procedure for fixing your problem using Intel's Linux updater. My Update #1 even called out the Windows updater, just in case you couldn't get the Linux updater to work properly (which you couldn't). Without my answer, you wouldn't have any idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: yes, you're right, so plz update your answer.

Comment: @thinkmore Update done.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by installing the complete driver for intel network adapter on https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Intel-Ethernet-Adapter-Complete-Driver-Pack?product=47620.
And then restart to ubuntu, it fantastically works.

Answer (score 0):

to install the Intel drivers I suggest also to download them from sourceforge:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20stable/3.8.7/
this latest version 3.8.7 was not available on the intel site.
Then before running the command "make install" be sure to install:

> sudo apt install build-essential

this will avoid ERROR 2

Comment: I got this error even though I have build-essential installed:
UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI is too large...
Ideas?