# Network:1 UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers

Just purchased and installed a brand new Intex X520-10G-2S-X8 Dual Port SFP+ Adapter.
Ubuntu 20.04 not initializing the 2nd port. Showing 'UNCLAIMED'. Updated to the latest kernel and tried the steps outlined in this question [e1000e error -5 and UNCLAIMED network interface after installing ubuntu newly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223772/e1000e-error-5-and-unclaimed-network-interface-after-installing-ubuntu-newly)
Still unable to initialize the 2nd port.

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: enp11s0f0
       version: 01
       serial: 80:61:5f:0a:38:16
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 10000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.11.12-051112-generic firmware=0x800003df, 1.2898.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:26 memory:ee300000-ee37ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:ee380000-ee3fffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.1
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d020(size=32)
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep ixgbe
[   12.796254] ixgbe: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver
[   12.916621] ixgbe: Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Intel Corporation.
[   13.280656] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: Failed to allocate MSI-X interrupts. Err: -12
[   13.437447] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: Disabling SR-IOV support
[   13.685802] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: Disabling RSS support
[   14.025948] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: Multiqueue Disabled: Rx Queue count = 1, Tx Queue count = 1 XDP Queue count = 0
[   14.367566] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: 8.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x4 link at 0000:00:08.0 (capable of 32.000 Gb/s with 5.0 GT/s PCIe x8 link)
[   14.728778] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: MAC: 2, PHY: 14, SFP+: 3, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[   14.914401] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: 80:61:5f:0a:38:16
[   15.203035] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
[   15.398730] libphy: ixgbe-mdio: probed
[   15.597657] ixgbe: probe of 0000:0b:00.1 failed with error -5
[   16.106850] ixgbe 0000:0b:00.0 enp11s0f0: renamed from eth0
```

Only a single port is showing available 'enp11s0f0'

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:19:61:63:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:19:61:63:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp6s0
4: enp11s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:61:5f:0a:38:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Should have just been plug and play?

EDIT: There appears to be some issues allocating resources during initialization:

```
[    0.615831] pci 0000:0a:00.0: [8086:10fb] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.615920] pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xe0100000-0xe017ffff 64bit pref]
[    0.616018] pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xccc0-0xccdf]
[    0.616105] pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xe00f8000-0xe00fbfff 64bit pref]
[    0.616203] pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff pref]
[    0.616340] pci 0000:0a:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 0x184: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.0: VF(n) BAR0 space: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] (contains BAR0 for 64 VFs)
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 0x190: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.0: VF(n) BAR3 space: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] (contains BAR3 for 64 VFs)
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.0: 16.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x8 link at 0000:00:07.0 (capable of 32.000 Gb/s with 5.0 GT/s PCIe x8 link)
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: [8086:10fb] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xe0180000-0xe01fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: reg 0x18: [io  0xcce0-0xccff]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: reg 0x20: [mem 0xe00fc000-0xe00fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: reg 0x30: [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff pref]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: reg 0x184: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: VF(n) BAR0 space: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] (contains BAR0 for 64 VFs)
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: reg 0x190: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]
[    0.616439] pci 0000:0a:00.1: VF(n) BAR3 space: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] (contains BAR3 for 64 VFs)
[    0.745942] pci 0000:0a:00.1: can't claim BAR 6 [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff pref]: address conflict with 0000:0a:00.0 [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff pref]
[    0.746842] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xee380000-0xee3fffff pref]
[    0.746936] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.747029] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.747125] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.747218] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.747313] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.747406] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.747500] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.747594] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.751531] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.751625] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.751719] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.751811] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.751904] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.751997] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.752090] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.752182] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.752275] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.752374] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.752467] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.752564] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.752658] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.752750] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.752844] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.754440] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.760030] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff 64bit pref]
[    0.760129] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xee380000-0xee3fffff pref]
[    0.760222] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.760314] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.760408] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 6: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
[    0.760483] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
[    0.760580] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.760672] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.760765] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.760857] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.760951] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.761043] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.761137] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.761229] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.761323] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.761418] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.761512] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.761607] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.770235] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff 64bit pref]
[    0.770336] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xee380000-0xee3fffff pref]
[    0.770428] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.770521] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.770615] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.770707] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.770800] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.770893] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.770986] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.771079] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.771172] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.771264] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.771363] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.771455] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.771553] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.771658] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.781886] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff 64bit pref]
[    0.781985] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xee380000-0xee3fffff pref]
[    0.782077] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.782169] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.782263] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.782362] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.782458] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.782555] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.782649] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.782741] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.782835] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.782927] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.783021] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.783113] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.783206] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.783299] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.783396] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 2: assigned [io  0xd000-0xd01f]
[    0.783471] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 2: assigned [io  0xd020-0xd03f]
[    0.783552] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xee300000-0xee37ffff 64bit pref]
[    0.783653] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xee380000-0xee3fffff pref]
[    0.783745] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.783837] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 64bit pref]
[    0.783931] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.784023] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.784116] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.784208] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit pref]
[    0.784302] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.784396] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.784489] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.784585] pci 0000:0a:00.1: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.784679] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.784771] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.784865] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.784957] pci 0000:0a:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    2.145097] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: Failed to allocate MSI-X interrupts. Err: -12
[    2.145102] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: Disabling SR-IOV support
[    2.145106] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: Disabling RSS support
[    2.145159] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: Multiqueue Disabled: Rx Queue count = 1, Tx Queue count = 1 XDP Queue count = 0
[    2.145444] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: 16.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x8 link at 0000:00:07.0 (capable of 32.000 Gb/s with 5.0 GT/s PCIe x8 link)
[    2.145530] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: MAC: 2, PHY: 14, SFP+: 3, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    2.145535] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: 80:61:5f:0a:38:16
[    2.296647] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
[    2.327589] ixgbe: probe of 0000:0a:00.1 failed with error -5
[    2.330486] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0f0: renamed from eth0
```

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Comment: See https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/14687/Ethernet-Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-10-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-under-Linux- . You could also try booting to a 20.10 Ubuntu Live USB flash and see if that helps.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work, I will try a 20.10 live disk and see if it works there. Otherwise will try the card in a windows machine and see what happens there.

Comment: You're correct. The link is now broken. The Intel site has removed ALL downloads for the X520-10G-2S-X8 card. You may have to contact their support for further help.

Comment: Same issues on 20.10 Live USB. Trying windows now..

Comment: Works fine on Windows, will put back in Ubuntu server and see if any change.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Contact Intel and ask about firmware and driver downloads.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is an issue with the driver/firmware. I was able to update the cards firmware to the latest version. It also has no issue on another Ubuntu 20.04 installation, only on a different machine. The 20.10 Live USB was ran on the same machine the card is having issues in. This might be an issue with the hardware of the server and not the card?

Comment: If I understand what you're saying... you have TWO different 20.04 computers, and the card works in one, but not the other? Same version drivers? Same kernels? Similar .yaml files? Same BIOS settings for card/slot enable-ment? It's not even getting the MAC address for the 2nd port. Show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: Are you sure that the card is plugged into the proper speed PCI slot?

Comment: Yes you are correct, 2 separate ubuntu 20.04 systems. No I'm not sure about the PCI speed. `/etc/network/interfaces` is empty. The netplan only has configuration for the two motherboard nics. I tried a completely separate network adapter, this time a Chelsio T422-CR. This card has 4 ports and only 2 of them work. Interestingly it is the 2 RJ-45 ports working fine, the other two SFP+ ports are showing up as unclaimed aswell. It seems like any card with an SFP+ cage the system is unable to claim those ports..

Comment: The previously broken link at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/14687/Ethernet-Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-10-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-under-Linux- is now working again, so try and download the latest driver and see what happens. Also see https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/36773/Ethernet-Products for NVM/firmware updaters.

Comment: I was able to update the intel card firmware to latest and still had the problem. Here now I have another card from a different vendor giving the same symptoms. Chelsio T422-CR using cxgbe driver. Is there some way I can force the driver onto these unclaimed interfaces?

Comment: Have you looked at the Intel site at the second link, and checked for an NVM updater? You may have to scroll down the page a bit to find the one for your Intel X520. Also check your PCI slot speed, maybe in the BIOS, or the User Manual, and assure the card is in the appropriate speed PCI slot. It looks like it should be in an X16 slot.

Comment: Let me write a quick update for your .yaml file, and see if it helps. Give me a minute.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Try this .yaml file with the Intel card in a x16 PCI slot...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enp11s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`