# Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LAN Showing Unclaimed

Tags: networking, drivers

First time Ubuntu user.

Fresh Install of 22.04 onto a Dell Latitude 5420 Laptop. During the install wireless was connected to the internet and driver updates enabled. The device is on the supported list.

No additional drives are detected in the update app and all other updates are installed.

lshw -C net shows the
Network:1 UNCLAIMED
Ethernet connection (13) I219-LM
Intel Corporation

How is the best way to get the drivers?

I can gather any info needed :)

```
rob@PLEX:~$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
0000:00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-LM [8086:15fb] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (13) I219-LM [1028:0a20]
    Kernel modules: e1000e
0000:71:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:0a20]




sudo dmesg | grep e1000e

[    0.968438] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    0.968440] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.968683] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.054124] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[    1.108113] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -5
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about a wired or a wireless connection? Ethernet is a wired connection.

Comment: Wireless is working well.

Comment: The wired / LAN is what is showing unclaimed / not working

Comment: Is it connected?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Yes t is connected.

Comment: The driver is not loaded. Lets see why. Please add output of `sudo dmesg | grep e1000e`

Comment: Try to run `sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sleep 2 && sudo modprobe e1000e`. Does it start working? And also check if there are bios updates.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213667 It is a bios bug, check for upgrades.

Comment: Thanks, will try now

Comment: I have seen the attached link that mentions using different drives. How do you install a new driver in Ubuntu ?

Comment: This is not about installing drivers.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223772/e1000e-error-5-and-unclaimed-network-interface-after-installing-ubuntu-newly